# delete[] causing heap corruption

Tags: c++, heap-memory, delete-operator, heap-corruption

I'm well aware that there are countless problems like this, but I searched for hours and couldn't understand what I did wrong so I would really appreciate your help. (I'm new to programming)

I need to create a dictionary manager of sorts as part of my homework but I seem to have a problem with deleting words.
I get an error message "...triggered a breakpoint".

The usual answer people get to this problem is that this is heap corruption caused by going out of bounds but I can't see if and how I caused this.

I already made something similar with bus info management and it worked perfectly so that makes me even more confused... (Obviously, I did not make the mechanism exactly the same, but even after looking at my previous code I couldn't isolate the problem)

I added the functions I believe are of concern,

The adding function:

```
void Add_Word(char**& dictionary, int& dictionary_size, char word[])
{
    char** temp = new char*[dictionary_size + 1];   // Create a new array of appropriate size.

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dictionary_size; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = dictionary[i];    // Copy head pointers addresses for all existing items.
    }
    temp[i] = new char[strlen(word)];   // Add the space for the new word,
    temp[i][strlen(word)] = '\0';   // mark its end

    strcpy_s(temp[i], strlen(word) + 1, word);  // then copy it.
    // I'm really not so sure about what I should put in the buffer length but
    // strlen(word) + 1 seemed to work... I know... not good, but strlen(word) alone caused a problem.

    if (dictionary_size > 0)
        delete []dictionary;    // Delete previous head pointers array if there are any and
    dictionary = temp;  // reset the main pointer to the address of the new one.

    dictionary_size++;  // Finally, increase dictionary_size.
}
```

The deleting function:

```
void Delete_Word(char**& dictionary, int& dictionary_size, char* word)
{
    // !!! This is where the crash thingy happens.
    delete[] Search_For_Word(dictionary, dictionary_size, word);    // Delete the word from the dictionary.
    // Search_For_Word returns a pointer to the word it receives, from the dictionary.

    char** temp = new char*[dictionary_size - 1];   // Create a new array of appropriate size.

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dictionary_size; i++)
    {
        if (dictionary[i][0])
            temp[i] = dictionary[i];    // Copy the head pointers of the existing
           // items to the new array except for the deleted word.
    }

    delete[] dictionary;    // Delete previous head pointers array and
    dictionary = temp;  // reset the main pointer to the address of the new one.

    dictionary_size--;  // Finally, decrease dictionary_size.
}
```

EDIT: Any parts that are excessively inefficient or obviously broken are likely a result of me messing with my code trying to figure this out on my own (such as the calling 3 times to strlen mentioned (thanks again for that, kfsone...), or forgetting to +1 it for the '\0' to mark the end of a string 
--actually, no, if we go by obvious you won't tell me my mistakes @.@).

As for the reason I'm dealing with char instead of strings and vectors please allow me to quote myself: "...as part of my **homework**". I just barely started programming. That, and I want to grasp the basics before moving on to using the more comfortable higher-up tools.

Comment: **AHRRG!** Why you're going to deal with raw `char` pointers to implement this with [tag:c++]?? Use s.th. like `std::map<std::string,std::string>` please, and forget about getting the memory management right!!

Comment: What about this: temp[i] = new char[strlen(word)]; It must be strlen(word)+1; that's where your corruption happens

Comment: I realize you tagged this as C++, because you're using `new` and `delete`, but what you're doing is *C+*, or *C#-*, not C++. I'd guess you screwed the heap up doing `delete[] Search_For_Word ...` but your code looks variously buggy (off-by-1 string errors etc), you show a poor understanding of pointers and c-strings, and you don't use any of the actual facets of C++. Either of the following two statements replaces most of your code, eliminates the bugs, and is hugely more efficient. `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>`.

Comment: http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp.pdf

Comment: This code: `temp[i] = new char[strlen(word)]; temp[i][strlen(word)] = '\0'; strcpy_s(temp[i], strlen(word) + 1, word);` is AWFUL. It calls strlen 3 times (expensive), it passes strlen (*plus 1!* to strcpy_s (stupid, stupid, stupid), it adds the '\0' before the strcpy (all kinds of wrong), there aren't many ways you could get `temp[i] = strdup(word);` more wrong. Oh... And C/C++ array indexes are zero based, so `temp[i][strlen(word)] = '0'` always writes to one element past the end of the allocation.

Comment: @kfsone I appreciate the feedback, I just wish you could pass it with a less insulting tone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is now working.

It was wrong all over.
I messed up pretty much any part that I could regarding the dynamic memory while trying to fix it before.

I initially didn't care about calling 3 times to strlen becuase it's just homework and a very small program but I guess it's better to get used to do things the right way...
I also dropped the copy which I evidently don't understand very well in favour of a simple for loop.

```
// Add function. The rest is cut.
    int word_length = strlen(word);

    temp[i] = new char[word_length + 1];    // Added +1 here.
    temp[i][word_length] = '\0';    /* This was correct after all.
    the word_length index is the correct ending.*/

    for (int j = 0; j < word_length; j++)   // copy replaced by for loop.
        temp[i][j] = word[j];
    // cut
}

void Delete_Word(char**& dictionary, int& dictionary_size, char* word)
{
    delete[] Search_For_Word(dictionary, dictionary_size, word);
   // There was a -1 mistake here I made in order to try and fix the thing earlier.
// No need for more, it works perfectly now.
```

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
temp[i] = new char[strlen(word)]
```

To:

```
temp[i] = new char[strlen(word)+1]
```

Comment: Fixed this but the problem is till there.
I also: temp[i][strlen(word) **+ 1**] = '\0';
even though, if I understood kfsone correctly, the '\0' will go to the last slot anyway.

Comment: Should be `temp[i][strlen(word)] = '\0'` (without the `+1`)

Answer (score 3):

This is C++, why are you not using std::string instead of char buffers?

If you must use char buffer strings and the secure forms of strcpy_s know that the buffer length must always be the size of the destination buffer, never a strlen function. In your case it is a bit understandable since you created the buffer with the strlen function. But what you should do is set the value into a variable and then use that any time you need the buffer size.

Also, and where I think your bug is, you are writing temp[i][strlen(word)] = '\0'; But the actual indexes of the buffer go from 0 to strlen(word)-1 so you're writing outside the allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several problems.

First, if you want to allocate a C-style string on the heap using `new[]`, then you must pay attention to the terminating `NUL` character.

So, if you want to do a deep copy from a string `word`, then you must calculate enough room, considering `strlen(word) + 1`: the `+1` is for the terminating `NUL` character.
e.g.:

```
// Original code (wrong):
//
//     temp[i] = new char[strlen(word)];
//
// New code:
temp[i] = new char[strlen(word) + 1]; // consider terminating NUL (+1)
```

Moreover, following your code with explicit `new[]`s and `delete[]`s is not easy.
In *modern C++*, you may want to use convenient robust container classes like `std::vector` and string classes like `std::string`, instead of raw C-style pointers and strings.

You can simply store a list of strings using a `std::vector<std::string>`, and `vector::push_back()` method to add new strings to the vector. No need to complicate code with `new[]`, `delete[]`, `strcpy_s()`, etc.

And if you want to deep-copy strings, you can just use the simple natural overload of `operator=` for `std::string`, and copy constructors; e.g. `std::string temp = word;` will work just fine.